# How to redirect outputs and errors to an external file from within lxterminal?

Tags: linux, logging, sh, stdout, stderr

I run compiled python program like this on my linux box (it runs automatically after start lxterminal LXDE lxsession autostart):

```
@lxterminal -e sudo /home/user/app.exe > /home/user/app.out 2>&1
```

I am getting output messages (errors, other output messages) in lxterminal but no idea how to save outputs and errors to app.out file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Redirection, such as `> /home/user/app.out`, is done by the shell, not by the command being invoked by the shell.

As such, your example would redirect the output of `lxterminal` to `/home/user/app.out`, not the output of `sudo /home/user/app.exe`.

To address this, you'll want to invoke the shell within your `lxterminal` session to redirect the output:

```
@lxterminal -e sh -c "sudo /home/user/app.exe > /home/user/app.out 2>&1"
```